# Mongoose schema constructor not recognized

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, typeerror

I have a Node server using Mongoose, with a User schema. I am trying to write a signup function, but I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: this is not a constructor

This is occurring in this code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passwordHasher = require('password-hash-and-salt');

var User = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  hashedPassword: String,
  email: String
});

User.statics.signup = function(un, pw, em, cb){
  this.findOne( { $or:[ {'username': un}, {'email': em} ] }, function(err, person){
    if (err) cb(false, "Server error");
    else if (person == null){
      passwordHasher(pw).hash(function(error, hash){
        console.log(un, pw, em);
        if (error) cb(false, "Server error");
        var newUser = new User({ username: un, hashedPassword: hash, email: em});
                      ^ (location of error)
        newUser.save(function(err){
          if (err) cb(false, "Server error");
          else {
            cb(true, null);
          }
        });
      });
    }
    else if (person.email == em && person.username == un) cb(false, "Username and email are taken");
    else if (person.email == em) cb(false, "Email is taken");
    else if (person.username == un) cb(false, "Username is taken");
  });
}

var model = mongoose.model('User', User);
module.exports = model;
```

I am not very familiar with Javascript, so it could be a simple typo I missed somewhere else in the method. However, I did research any problems I could find with similar error the suggested changes did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can not save a new object using schema. Try this way:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passwordHasher = require('password-hash-and-salt');

var User = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  hashedPassword: String,
  email: String
});

var model = mongoose.model('User', User);
module.exports = model;


module.exports.statics.signup = function(un, pw, em, cb){
  model.findOne( { $or:[ {'username': un}, {'email': em} ] }, function(err, person){
    if (err) cb(false, "Server error");
    else if (person == null){
      passwordHasher(pw).hash(function(error, hash){
        console.log(un, pw, em);
        if (error) cb(false, "Server error");
        var newUser = new model({ username: un, hashedPassword: hash, email: em});
                      ^ (change this)
        newUser.save(function(err){
          if (err) cb(false, "Server error");
          else {
            cb(true, null);
          }
        });
      });
    }
    else if (person.email == em && person.username == un) cb(false, "Username and email are taken");
    else if (person.email == em) cb(false, "Email is taken");
    else if (person.username == un) cb(false, "Username is taken");
  });
}
```

hope this work

EDIT:  plese make sure model.statics exists, otherwise it will raise error
or you can skip statics and assign the function directly as below:

```
module.exports.signup = function(...
```

Comment: This is giving me `TypeError: Cannot set property 'signup' of undefined`, on the line `module.exports.statics.signup = ...`

Comment: That's because your module.exports.statics is 'undefined'.

Comment: You have to make sure your model.statics exists, otherwise you could do: module.exports.signup = function(...

Comment: That was it, thanks! If you want to edit your post to mention that statics is undefined at the top, that would probably help others who are looking. I'll mark as accepted either way.